# Why is colon right associative in this expression?

Tags: haskell, brackets

Because function application is left associative in Haskell, I expect

```
'x':'y':"z"
```

to be equivalent to `('x':'y'):"z"`.
`('x':'y')` is an error, because `'y'` is not a list as it should be.

But `'x':'y':"z"` evaluates to `"xyz"` like `'x':('y':"z")`. So the implicit brackets are right associative here. How can we explain this?

Comment: This is application of an infix operator `(:)`, which is defined as right-associative. `x : xs` is not the same as `f x`.

Comment: You can customize the fixity of operators with infix declarations. The precedence and associativity of the built-in operators, as well as the means of declaring custom fixity, are detailed [in Ch 4 of the Haskell 98 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's already quite informative.

Answer (score 10):

It's [declared in `GHC.Types`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Types.html#line-48) (which is used by the `Prelude`)

```
infixr 5 :
```

This is known as a [fixity declaration](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.2).

Answer (score 1):

luqui's anwser is the rigth one. If you think deeper on how lists are defined, you''l realize that It couldn't be otherway:

```
Prelude> :info []
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

so a list is either

1. "empty list"
2. "an element, a colon (cons) and a list"

That's a list an nothing else is a list, so:

```
 []   -- Is a list -> by condition 1
 1    -- Is not a list

 1:[] -- Is a list by condition 2 -> an element, a colon, a list (empty)
 1:2  -- Is not a list. does not follow any condition -> an element, a colon, an element

 1:(2:[])  -- Is a list by condition 2 -> an element, a colon, a list (2:[])
 (1:[]):[] -- Is NOT a list -> a list (1:[]), a colon, a list
 (1:2):[]  -- Is not a list -> (1:2) is not an element

 [1,2,3,4] -- Is syntactic sugar for 1:(2:(3:(4:[])))
```

So if `:` was left associative, we would end up with the case `(1:2):[]` which is not a list by definition.

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. The fixity has nothing to do with either the data type definition, and the examples you show are misleading. Of course it could be another way: what if you defined it with `infixl 5 :`?

Comment: As I said, the correct answer is luqui's one. `:` is right associative because it is defined as so. The point of my answer is to justify why: If you define `infixl 5 :` then, this expression wouldn't compile `1:2:3:[] `, you'd need to add explicit parenthesis `1:(2:(3:[]))`. Another example, If you'd try to pattern match a list with at least two element you'd end up with the following code `f (x1:(x2:xs))`.which is less readble than the current `f (x1:x2:xs)`. Of course you can define `infixl 5 :` but it would be a bad desing decision because of how data is defined. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Right, but saying that it's a design decision is different from saying "It couldn't be otherway", which is what you say in the answer. Your answer makes it seem like the `:` operator works the way it does just from the data declaration: it's important to point out that it *could* have worked another way, but the right-associativity was chosen simply because it allows for fewer parenthesis. In fact, if the data declaration alone was used, the default associativity would have been chosen, which is `infixl 9`.

Comment: `(1:[]):[]` is a list though - a list of `[Num]`. `(1:[])` is a list for sure but here it is just "some" element as well.